# problem install pip ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, python, python3, pipe

I'm doing this to install `pip`:

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

But when I try use the command I have this error:

```
# pip3 install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in main
    from pip._internal.utils.entrypoints import _wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
```

I got the same message when I did `pip3 --version`:

```
# pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in main
    from pip._internal.utils.entrypoints import _wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I need help to fix it.

Comment: It's named pip.

Comment: You may also want to consider update to 18.04 or 20.04 16.04 EOL is April this year.

Answer (score 0):

you may try:

```
    $sudo apt-get autoremove
    $sudo apt-get update
    $sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
```

then, while usig pip for  installing pakages, use:

```
$sudo pip2 install <package>
```

However, using:

```
$sudo pip install <package>
```

may still give you the same error message. It is more likely related to no support for some pip versions, anymore.

This solution was tested on:

```
Distributor 
ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

```
It was run on 32bit Chromenotebook
```